# magento-2 Language package uploadin

Tags: magento2.2, language-package, cpanel

i know all process and commands to be run after uploading language package in cPanel. but the point i'm confusing on is that, where do i have to upload that .zip file in the cPanel?
in which directory should i upload the language package?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload it in currently active theme.

> app/i18n/Vendor/fr_FR/fr_FR.csv

For more details you can check [GitHub mageplaza](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-french-language-pack).

Don't forget to run **Upgrade** and **Deploy** commands.

Hope it will help you !